# QuicKeys no longer runs in Catalina, how to run AppleScript on schedule?

Tags: applescript

don't use Calendar instead, it always fails.
QuicKeys is always promising although it can't wake up the Mac itself.

Comment: Use launchd and the osascript command line command. You have to create a plist file to run osascript on a schedule with launchd. All of these things can be found via google.

Answer (score 0):

[Keyboard Maestro](http://www.keyboardmaestro.com/) is a worthy replacement for QuicKeys, which can do this and many more things with a GUI and a very active user community.

You could use `launchd`. Here’s an example which will run the file `/Users/foo/my/applescript.scpt` at 4:00 p.m. (aka 1600)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.FOO.MYAPPLESCRIPT</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/usr/bin/osascript</string>
        <string>/Users/foo/my/applescript.scpt</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <false/>
    <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
    <string>/tmp/com.FOO.MYAPPLESCRIPT.log</string>
    <key>StandardOutPath</key>
    <string>/tmp/com.FOO.MYAPPLESCRIPT.log</string>
    <key>StartCalendarInterval</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Hour</key>
        <integer>16</integer>
        <key>Minute</key>
        <integer>0</integer>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Keyboard Maestro can wake a Mac if you want. `launchd` will not, but will run when it wakes up.